# How to get marked rows in the XPages Extension Library <xe:dataView> design element?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I have a XPage with  design element. How can I get list of checked rows to post it to an agent?

```
<xe:dataView id="dataView1" columnTitles="true"
    expandedDetail="true" var="dview1" 
    openDocAsReadonly="false" rows="15" showCheckbox="true"
    showHeaderCheckbox="true">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the client-side, you can use Dojo. The following CSJS script will return NoteIds for all selected rows:

```
dojo.query(".lotusFirstCell > input:checked").attr('value')
```

For the server side, you can grab the IDs of selected documents by:

```
var idList = getComponent("dataView1").getSelectedIds();
```

This will return a string array of NoteIDs. Then pass it to an in-memory document and call the agent.

```
var doc = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("IDList", IDList);

var agent:NotesAgent=database.getAgent("SomeAgent");
agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc);
```

Comment: Yes, I have found it already. But this is SSJS. How to get the same in the client?
Thank you!

Comment: You mean client-side javascript? I'm confused, because you asked about passing those into an agent.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to get the list of ids in the client javascript?

Comment: You can grab them with Dojo: `dojo.query(".lotusFirstCell > input:checked").attr('value')` will return the array containing id's.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! 
This is exactly what I need:

`var IDs = dojo.query(".xspFirstCell > input:checked").attr('value');`