# Adding a document to another document through modal checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I'm new to xpages and IBM in general as well as I'm new to JavaScript. So to make you understand my question a little bit easier I've added an example of what I want to do.

Example: I create a Person document, now I want to add an event to that Person and vice-versa (meaning when I add an event to the person, person gets added to that event).

So I'm using document read-only mode to preview the Person document and inside that read-only mode I have a `<xp:panel>` which contains bootstrap panel. In the bootstrap panel's header theres a button that's connected to the modal, which contains a view of event documents.In bootstrap panel's body there's a view where I preview added events.

In modal, I added checkbox in the first column, so I can select the items I want to add to Person document.

What action would I need to add to modal's "Add" button, to add the selected documents to the Person document?

```
<xp:panel>
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:!DodajOseb.isNewNote() !DodajOseb.isEditable()}]]></xp:this.rendered>

        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:60%">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Events
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin-left:80%;">
                        Add an event
                    </button>
                </h3>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                                </button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">
                                    Choose events&#160;<small>that you want to add</small>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>
                                    <xp:panel>
                                        <xp:this.data>
                                            <xp:dominoView var="DogodekView" viewName="Dogodki_Rez" keys="#{javascript:sessionScope.imeDogodka}">
                                            </xp:dominoView>
                                        </xp:this.data>
                                        <xp:viewPanel rows="7" id="viewPanel1" viewStyle="width:100.0%">
                                            <xp:this.facets>
                                                <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                                                </xp:pager>
                                            </xp:this.facets>

                                            <xp:this.data>
                                                <xp:dominoView var="Dogodki" viewName="Dogodki" keys="#{javascript:sessionScope.imeDogodka}">
                                                </xp:dominoView>
                                            </xp:this.data>

                                            <xp:viewColumn columnName="NMnaziv" id="viewColumn2" style="text-align:center" showCheckbox="true">
                                                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Event" id="viewColumnHeader2" style="text-align:center">
                                                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                                            </xp:viewColumn>
                                            <xp:viewColumn columnName="RadioButton" id="viewColumn4" style="text-align:center">
                                                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Duration" id="viewColumnHeader4" style="text-align:center">
                                                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                                            </xp:viewColumn>
                                            <xp:viewColumn columnName="TXlokacija" id="viewColumn15" style="text-align:center">
                                                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Location" id="viewColumnHeader15" style="text-align:center">
                                                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                                            </xp:viewColumn>
                                            <xp:viewColumn columnName="AUorganizator" id="viewColumn16" style="text-align:center">
                                                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Author" id="viewColumnHeader16" style="text-align:center">
                                                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                                            </xp:viewColumn>
                                        </xp:viewPanel>
                                    </xp:panel>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                <xp:button value="Save" id="button6">
                                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
                                </xp:button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <xp:panel id="panelMain">
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="Dogodki">
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" style="display:none;">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://*var vw:NotesView = database.getView("(vwPovezava)"); requestScope.data = new Array(@DbLookup("","(vwPovezava)","385A946ECD7C3207C1257E58002DE8A3",2),"467DD3771032D779C1257E570043CF5D");}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <xp:label value="" id="label2">Event</xp:label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <xp:label value="" id="label4">Duration</xp:label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <xp:label value="" id="label5">Starting date</xp:label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <xp:label value="" id="label6">Ending date</xp:label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <xp:label value="" id="label7">Location</xp:label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <xp:label value="" id="label8">Author</xp:label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <xp:br></xp:br>
                    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="indexData" value="#{javascript:requestScope.data}" style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="row" rows="0">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" style="display:none;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var vw = database.getView("Dogodki"); requestScope.docData = vw.getDocumentByKey(rowData);}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="event" tagName="div" style="float:left;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return requestScope.docData.getItemValueString("NMnaziv");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="duration" tagName="div" style="float:left;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return requestScope.docData.getItemValueString("RadioButton");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="startingDate" tagName="div" style="float:left;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return requestScope.docData.getItemValue("TXodDatuma");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="endingDate" tagName="div" style="float:left;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return requestScope.docData.getItemValue("TXdoDatuma");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="location" tagName="div" style="float:left;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return requestScope.docData.getItemValueString("TXlokacija");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="author" tagName="div" style="float:left;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return requestScope.docData.getItemValueString("AUorganizator");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;">&#160;</div>
                        </div>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </xp:panel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xp:panel>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that rather than trying to add the events to the Person document, that you simply add the Person's name to an attendee field on each Event document selected. Then, you can display the events to which the person has been added using what we'd call in 'old Notes', a single-category embedded view.

The challenge is that you have that modal, but the values aren't saved anywhere. Saving the document when the data is not bound to document means that the checkbox column choices have no meaning. It's all currently just a display of information. If you re-opened the document using that XPage, nothing would be checked when you re-opened your modal.

See the answer by @SerdarBasegmez to this question for how to add the Person's name to each document that's checked: [How to get marked rows in the XPages Extension Library <xe:dataView> design element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882772/how-to-get-marked-rows-in-the-xpages-extension-library-xedataview-design-elem)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wrote the question wrong, my events (to be seen in Person document) are in the repeater not the view, but does that change things, or is it still the same as if I was trying to add events to the view? I'm sorry for the trouble, but I am kinda new to javascript and xpages.

Comment: In either case, you have to add a value to a document. Serdar's answer provides some guidance in how to do that.